# Function not working properly. Please help

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm having trouble with the function setUpTranslation(). 
//The purpose of this function is to place the French phrases into the document and set up the event handlers for the mousedown and mouseup events.

//These are the arrays of the French phrases and English phrases that I have do place into the document:

```
var english = new Array();
english[0] = "This hotel isn't far from the Eiffel Tower.";
english[1] = "What time does the train arrive?";
english[2] = "We have been waiting for the bus for one half-hour.";
english[3] = "This meal is delicious";
english[4] = "What day is she going to arrive?";
english[5] = "We have eleven minutes before the train leaves!";
english[6] = "Living in a foreign country is a good experience.";
english[7] = "Excuse me! I'm late!";
english[8] = "Is this taxi free?";
english[9] = "Be careful when you go down the steps.";


var french = new Array();
french[0] = "Cet h&#244;tel n'est pas loin de la Tour Eiffel.";
french[1] = "A quelle heure arrive le train?";
french[2] = "Nous attendons l'autobus depuis une demi-heure.";
french[3] = "Ce repas est d&#233;licieux";
french[4] = "Quel jour va-t-elle arriver?";
french[5] = "Nous avons onze minutes avant le d&#233;part du train!";
french[6] = "Habiter dans un pays &#233;tranger est une bonne exp&#233;rience.";
french[7] = "Excusez-moi! Je suis en retard!";
french[8] = "Est-ce que ce taxi est libre?";
french[9] = "Faites attention quand vous descendez l'escalier.";
```

//function I'm having trouble with

```
function setUpTranslation(){
var phrases = document.getElementByTagName("p");
    for (i =0; i<phrases.length; i++){
     phrases[i].number =i;
     phrases[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML =french[i];

     phrases[i].childNodes[1].onmousedown =function(){
     swapFE(event);

     phrases[i].childNodes[1].onmouseup =function(){
     swapEF(event); 
     };
  };
}
```

//Below are the other two functions swapFE() and swapEF(). The purpose of the function swapFE() is to exchange the French phrase for the English translation
//The purpose of the function swapEF() is to exchange the English translation for the French phrase.

```
function swapFE(e){
var phrase =e.srcElement;
var parent =phrase.parentNode;
var idnum =parent.childNodes[0];
var phrasenum =parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
    phrase.innerText =english[phrasenum]; 
}

function swapEF(e){
var phrase =e.srcElement;
var parent =phrase.parentNode;
var idnum =parent.childNodes[0];
var phrasenum =parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
    phrase.innerText =french[phrasenum];
}
```

//Not sure if these are right. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: its a bit confusing question.it would be great if you make your problem and requirement more clear.For example if you are having trouble with the existing code what problem is that etc etc

Comment: "La plume de ma tante est sur la table" means "My hovercraft is full of eels." HTH.

Comment: @Ed learn something new every day!  I'm going to use this in ALL of my applications!

Comment: One point, more seriously, is that your "onmousedown" handler has an unmatched open curly brace. You need a matching right curly brace after the call to swapFE(event);, to end the function. If this is a direct copy'n'paste from your code, I would expect that it's not even running, because of that error.

Comment: One note as you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EsUmS/1/ the phrase.innerText should be phrase.innerHTML or the text is improperly handled on the french part of the accents &#244;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your HTML looks like this

```
<p><span>1</span><span></span></p>
<p><span>2</span><span></span></p>
...
<p><span>10</span><span></span></p>
```

Then all you need to do is to add the curly bracket after `swapFE(event);` (points for Mr Plunkett) and replace `getElementByTagName` with `getElementsByTagName` (you're missing an 's' in there).

One additional thing to note: If the English phrase is shorter than the French, the container might shrink when the `onmousedown` event fires. If this shrinkage causes the mouse cursor to be positioned outside the container, the subsequent `onmouseup` event will not be triggered. Of course, if you are using block elements (e.g. a `<div>`) instead of my assumed `<span>`, that likely isn't an issue. In any case, it's probably better to attach the event listeners to the `<p>` tags instead.